# Repeated messages mosquitto MQTT broker to amazon IoT Service using persistence

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Raspberry with a mosquitto broker on it and bridged with amazon IoT service. https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/

This is my mosquitto.conf file:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

This is the bridge.conf that is inside the /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

```
# =================================================================
# Bridges to AWS IOT
# =================================================================

# AWS IoT endpoint, use AWS CLI 'aws iot describe-endpoint'
connection awsiot
address xxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8883

# Specifying which topics are bridged
topic awsiot_to_localgateway in 1
topic localgateway_to_awsiot/iot out 1
topic both_directions both 1

# Setting protocol version explicitly
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false

# Bridge connection name and MQTT client Id,
# enabling the connection automatically when the broker starts.
cleansession true
clientid bridgeawsiot
start_type automatic
notifications false
log_type all

# =================================================================
# Certificate based SSL/TLS support
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
#Path to the rootCA
bridge_cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/rootCA.pem

# Path to the PEM encoded client certificate
bridge_certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/cert.crt

# Path to the PEM encoded client private key
bridge_keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/private.key
```

All works fine. But, If I remove the ethernet cable to test the pesistence. When the comunications are reestablished. The broker send repeated messages to the amazon IoT service.

This is the message that I'm sending

```
char dataToSend[] = "Message Id: ";
counter++;

snprintf(dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) + 10, "Message Id: %d", counter);
app_mqtt_publish(&dataToSend);
```

Is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: You haven't included the details of the bridge in that configuration. Also what sort of messages are you sending, what QOS and are they retained?

Comment: Sorry @hardillb... Question edited. The QOS is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version of (part of) the MQTT spec:

- QOS 0 - > Messages may be delivered
- QOS 1 -> Messages will be delivered at least once
- QOS 2 -> Messages will be delivered once and only once.

So if messages have not been acknowledged then there is a chance that QOS 1 messages will be delivered again. They should have the DUP flag set in the header so the receiving broker should know they may have been delivered already.

IIRC AWS-IoT doesn't support QOS 2 so you may have just put up with this.

Comment: It's a normal behaivour that after 10 seconds, more or less, the retained messages are deleted? Because if I lose the comunications for a short period of time, the messages in queue are sent. But If I lose the comunications for more than 1 minute, seems that all message in queue are deleted because I don't receive any message in the Amazon IOT

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT doesn't support `cleansession false`. The consequence for the bridge is that, when:

- you have an error sending a message
- and have `persistence true`
- and didn't effectually disconnect
- and the QoS > 0 or even QoS = 0 if `queue_qos0_messages true`

=> messages are saved in db.

But if the client automatically set to the bridge effectually disconnects, the `cleansession true` tells the broker to do not persist the data, so it clears the db for this client.

Wish that AWS IoT didn't disconnect when you send `cleansession false`, so we could keep this local cache...

ps: The "client automatically set to the bridge" is that, when you set a bridge between two brokers, a client is created to subscribe to one and always publish to the other.